# django only show the highest value of m2m in template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

Hej!

I have a table view with multiple columns one of them contains a m2m field from the model. I dont want all values (if multiple values/entries are given for that m2m) only the highest.

Example:

- 1890 bonbons
- 30 bonbons
- 300000 bonbons

i only want to show the 300000 bonbons in that cell and not all 3 values.

```
{% for candymarket in mall %}
    <td>
        {% for bon in candymarket.bonbon_color.all %}
             {{bon.value}} | {{bon.color}}
        {% endfor %}
   </td>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I filter inside the template? I still want to be able to get all values in a detail view.

Is there something like `{% if bon.value|length > 200 %}` only with is max?

Any help or link to a documentation is appreciated! :)

```py
class CandyMarket(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length = 500,
        unique = True
    )
    bonbon= models.ManyToManyField(
        Bon,
        verbose_name = "BON",
        through = "BonForCandyMarket",
        blank = True,
        related_name = "bonbon_in_market"
    )


class BonForCandyMarket(models.Model):
    market= models.ForeignKey(
        Candymarket,
        on_delete = models.PROTECT,
        related_name = "bonbon_color"
    )
    bon= models.ForeignKey(
        Bon,
        on_delete = models.PROTECT,
        related_name = "market_with_bonbon"
    )
    value= models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )


class Bon(models.Model):
    description_english = models.CharField(
        max_length = 500,
        unique = True
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `last` [builtin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#last)

```
{% for candymarket in mall %}
    <td>
        {% with candymarket.bonbon_color.all|last as highest_bon %}
            {{ highest_bon.value }} | {{ highest_bon.color }}
        {% endwith %}
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

and set default [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/#ordering) in `BonForCandyMarket` model `Meta`

```
class BonForCandyMarket(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-value"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it is better not to handle such inside the `template`. If it is query related data then try to keep as much as possible inside your `view`. On template files, logic should be only for rendering components.

It is possible to [`aggregate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation) data to your query. In this case called `annotation` (that is a [per object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) aggregation):

views.py

```
from django.db.models import Max

def candy_mall(request):
    qs = (
        CandyMarket.objects.all()
        .annotate(highest_bon=Max("bonbon__market_with_bonbon__value"))
    )
    context={'mall': qs}
    return render(request, 'candy_mall.html', context=context)
```

candy_mall.html

```
...
<body>
    {% for candymarket in mall %}
    <div>
        <h1>{{candymarket.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{candymarket.highest_bon}}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
...
```